# How to use mapStateToProps in app.js file?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native router flux for Router navigation in my application. And I'm using redux and react-redux for accessing some state variables.

Using the below statement, redux functionality works fine in my application.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName);
```

Is there a way to use mapStateToProps in App.js file itself?

I'm using react-native-i18n npm package for language translation in my application. And I'm storing the current language in redux store. So if I change language in my application, the variable in redux store will be changed and the change is reflected in all screens. But the language change is not reflected to the headers and tab navigators, because it's in my app.js file.

How to listen to the state change in app.js file?

PFA my App.js file and sample file(Screen2.js) file.

Thanks in advance!!!

**App.js file:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider,connect } from 'react-redux';
import I18n from './locale/i18n';
import store from './Reducers/index';
import { Actions, ActionConst, Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const ConnectedRouter = connect()(Router);

let Scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key='Screen1' hideNavBar title='Screen1' component={Screen1}></Scene>
    <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true}>
      <Scene key="tab1" title={I18n.t('TabTile1')} icon={CustomComponenet} initial> 
        <Scene key="Screen2" component={Screen2} title="Screen2" initial/>
        <Scene key="Screen3" component={Screen3} title="Screen3"/>
      </Scene>

      <Scene key="tab2" title={I18n.t('TabTile2')} icon={CustomComponenet} initial>
        <Scene key="Screen4" component={Screen4} title="Screen4" initial/>
        <Scene key="Screen5" component={Screen5} title="Screen5"/>
      </Scene>
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
)

export default class App extends Component {     
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter scenes={Scenes} />
      </Provider>
    ) 
  }
}
```

**Screen2.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import I18n from '../locale/i18n'
import { Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../Actions/ActionTypes'

class Dashboard extends React.Component{

render(){
  I18n.locale = this.props.language;

  return(
    <View>.....</View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    language: state.Reducer.language,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen2);
```

Comment: Hi @BrunoEduardo, thanks for the reply. I could able to use the value of store variable by using store.getState(). But again when I change the value of store variable in some other screens(other than App.js), it's not reflected in App.js file. Now how do I listen or subscribe for that state change?

Comment: You want to listen for the change in your header components, right?

Comment: Yes I want to listen for language change in headers and tabs @BrunoEduardo

Comment: Ok, we might have to bash our heads a little bit on this one. I searched around and found an issue thread where Aksonov tells someone with a similar problem to pass a function instead of a value to the header, maybe try doing that and see what happens. Here's the link: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2677

Answer (score 2):

The `connect()` function only works in components that are inside a `<Provider>` tag, so you can't use it in your `App.js` since you're creating the store and providing it to `App.js`'s children.

That being said, you don't need to use `mapStateToProps`, just access the state by using `store.getState()` and `store.dispatch()`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @BrunoEduardo, instead of passing the value to the header, now I am using customized headers, where the language change is reflected.

HeaderComponent.js:

```
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {
      render(){    
          return (
              <View height={25}>
                  <Text>{I18n.t(this.props.title)}</Text>
              </View>
            );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      language: state.Reducer.language,
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderComponent);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Provider,connect } from 'react-redux';
    import I18n from './locale/i18n';
    import store from './Reducers/index';
    import { Actions, ActionConst, Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

    const ConnectedRouter = connect()(Router);

    let Scenes = Actions.create(
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key='Screen1' hideNavBar title='Screen1' component={Screen1}></Scene>
        <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true}>
          <Scene key="tab1" title='tabtitle1' icon={CustomComponenet} initial> 
            <Scene key="Screen2" component={Screen2} title="Screen2" navBar={HeaderComponent} initial/>
            <Scene key="Screen3" component={Screen3} title="Screen3" navBar={HeaderComponent}/>
          </Scene>

          <Scene key="tab2" title='tabtitle2' icon={CustomComponenet} initial>
            <Scene key="Screen4" component={Screen4} title="Screen4" navBar={HeaderComponent} initial/>
            <Scene key="Screen5" component={Screen5} title="Screen5" navBar={HeaderComponent}/>
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Scene>
    )

    export default class App extends Component {     
      render() {
        return(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter scenes={Scenes} />
          </Provider>
        ) 
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps!